# In a Tabulator table, how to add dropdown filter "with the input filter"

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In a Tabulator table, how can I add a dropdown filter "with the input filter" for columns, so if the dropdown is very long, one can type and filter the respective column.

I've been referring the document but it isn't giving me any proper solutions.

Comment: What document have you been referring to?

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list` header filter with the `autocomplete` option enabled and the `valuesList` option set to `true`.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Example", field:"example", headerFilter:"list", headerFilterParams:{autocomplete:true, valuesLookup:true, clearable:true}},
    ],
});
```

A demo of this in action can be found in the Header Filters Demo https://tabulator.info/examples/5.4#filter-header